# Android Sqlite Create syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I can't seem to find out what exactly I did wrong here. Seem to be getting a syntax error in my create command inside the `createNewTable` method.

> Android SQLite Insert Error (Syntax error code 1)

I've added my database code:

```
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_TIME_IN = "timeCheckIn";
private static final String KEY_TIME_OUT = "timeCheckOut";
private static final String KEY_LATITUDE_IN = "latCheckIn";
private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE_IN = "longCheckIn";
private static final String KEY_LATITUDE_OUT = "latCheckOut";
private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE_OUT = "longCheckOut";

public void createNewTable(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(int _id);
        Log.v("Database", "Adding Check in table: " + _id);
        String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + Integer.toString(_id) + "("
                + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME_IN + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME_OUT + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LATITUDE_IN + " REAL," + KEY_LONGITUDE_IN + " REAL," + KEY_LATITUDE_OUT + " REAL,"
                + KEY_LONGITUDE_OUT + " REAL" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);}
```

My logcat error is as follows:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE 1(date TEXT,timeCheckIn TEXT,timeCheckOut TEXT,latCheckIn REAL,longCheckIn REAL,latCheckOut REAL,longCheckOut REAL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a table name that starts with a number. Not sure if SQLite allows it, but in MySQL, if your table name is a number, then for every query, you need to specify the table number with double quotes. Try giving the table name a prefix

Comment: tick the answer and let others know the question is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is telling you unescaped table names are not allowed to start with a number, in this case the number 1. If you want to use numbers you must escape the table name with brackets, like so

```
String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE [" + Integer.toString(_id) + "] ("
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME_IN + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME_OUT + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_LATITUDE_IN + " REAL," + KEY_LONGITUDE_IN + " REAL," + KEY_LATITUDE_OUT + " REAL,"
        + KEY_LONGITUDE_OUT + " REAL" + ")";
```

Comment: @FaizHalde Yeah, I believe double quotes are Standard SQL. Though I find for some reason most database systems use brackets in examples and whatnot.

Comment: It's a matter of choice afterall